# Why do all instances have same health even though object generates random health

Tags: javascript, oop, instance

I am trying to troubleshoot a students Javascript code. Currently it looks something like this:

```
var Alien = {
    hp: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
}

var alien1 = new Object(Alien);
var alien2 = new Object(Alien);
```

When I call alien1.hp it equals 61 and alien2.hp it also equals 61. Why is this? How can I change it so the health is different for every instance of Alien. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Answer (score 4):

Because you have only a single `Alien`, you only call the RNG once. You probably want Alien to be its own thing, too, instead of using an `Object` constructor.

```
function Alien() { 
  this.hp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

> a1 = new Alien();
=> Alien {hp: 13}
> a2 = new Alien();
=> Alien {hp: 42}
```

This allows you to add methods to alien's prototype and so on, e.g.,

```
function Alien(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.hp   = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

Alien.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'Alien "' + this.name + '", HP: ' + this.hp;
}

tom = new Alien('Tom');
console.log("" + tom);
=> Alien "Tom", HP: 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always have only one `Alien` with the same value, i suggest using a function instead:

```
function Alien() {
    return { hp: Math.floor(Math.random()*100) };
};

var alien1 = new Object(Alien());
var alien2 = new Object(Alien());
```

This way, the `Alien` function will return a different object with a different random hp each time it's invoked.